# Counting the number of rows in an SQLite database for this week

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin

I have the following query that returns the count of books entered in the last 7 days. Is it possible to modify the query so that it only returns the count of those entered since the start of the week?

```
public int GetWeeklyCount()
 {
       var week = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-7);
       return database.ExecuteScalar<int>("SELECT count(*) FROM Book WHERE bookEntryTime > ?;", week);
 }
```

Comment: What does "start of the week" mean?

Comment: @CaiusJard From the beginning of Monday on any given week. For example, if `GetWeeklyCount()` was called on a Friday, it should return a count of all records entered between the start of Monday up to and including Friday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

People vary as to what they mean by the start of a week, but for example if you think a week starts on Monday:

```
var week = DateTime.Today;
while(week.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Monday)
    week = week.AddDays(-1);
return database.ExecuteScalar<int>("SELECT count(*) FROM Book WHERE bookEntryTime > ?;", week);
```

You could also straight to the math:

```
var week = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-(((int)DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek+6)%7));
return database.ExecuteScalar<int>("SELECT count(*) FROM Book WHERE bookEntryTime > ?;", week);
```

But to me it's relatively non-self-documenting for little performance advantage